# How can I get the total count and the count with the condition in the same SQL query?

Tags: sql, hive, conditional-aggregation

I have a table like this:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0 |
| 002 | 100 |

I want to make a table like this:

| total_count | fail_count | pass_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 0.5 |

May I know how to write in one Hive SQL query? Thanks.
the pass_rate is fail_count/total_count.

I tried to use `WHERE LENGTH(id) = 3`, but it returns 0 as count for me.

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN LENGTH(id) = 3 AND (value IS NULL OR value <= 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS fail_count 
FROM my_table
```

And this is the output of my SQL query:

| total_count | fail_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |

Comment: Use `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: How do you get the id_length_3 and pass_rate values?

Comment: assuming it is a "pass" when value > some threshold. Let's say 50: So the query could be like this. (knowing "true" will evaluate to 1, so summing all those 1 will be a count)   
SELECT COUNT(1) AS totalnumber,
       SUM(LENGTH(id) = 3) AS nrofidlenght3,
       SUM(value > 50) / COUNT(1) AS pass_rate 
FROM tableName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case expressions + aggregations like this:

```
select count(*) as total_count, 
       count(case when LENGTH(id) = 3 then 1 else null end) as id_length_3,
       sum(value)/count(*)/100 as pass_rate
   from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks. may i know if there have more than 1 condition, e.g. another column (x) value > 10,    
am i just add the condition before the 'then', just like this? 

select count(*) as total_count, 
       count(case when LENGTH(id) = 3 and x > 10 then 1 else null end) as fail_record,
       sum(value)/count(*)/100 as pass_rate
from mytable

Comment: @TingL yep, why not. Of course you can modify as you need.  But make sure that conversion (implicit in case of this condition `x>10`) works as expected. For example '0001' >10 gives True.  And '000X' >10 gives NULL, and the result of case expression will be NULL, count() does not counts NULLs

Comment: Thanks, i tried and that's work. But may i know that why i try ' Fail_Count / Total_Count * 100 as Pass_Rate' it will return error, and say that Error is cannot resolve '`Fail_Count`' given input columns, thanks.

Comment: @TingL It can't resolve columns calculated on the same level. Wrap into subquery:  `select Fail_Count / Total_Count * 100 as Pass_Rate from (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN LENGTH(id) = 3 AND (value IS NULL OR value <= 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS fail_count 
FROM my_table) s `